# For $X$ compact Hausdorff, can there be a closed discontinuous function $X\rightarrow X$? $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is compact Hausdorff then is every closed function $X\rightarrow X$ necessarily continuous? Or, $X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Edit: by a function being "closed" I mean it sends closed sets to closed sets.

A comment on my earlier question helped point out that if the compactness condition is dropped then the above statements fail: for example there is the function $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ sending $z\mapsto 1/z$ for $z\neq 0$ and $0\mapsto 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Y$ is a T1-space, any function $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ with finite image has the property that it sends closed sets to closed sets (which I assume is what you mean by a closed function, although typically one would apply that adjective only to functions that are continuous to begin with). If $X$ is not discrete, many of these will be discontinuous.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation!